# Plane tessellation $6^2*3^2$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, tessellations

An article I am reading mentioned "the plane tessellation $6^2*3^2$",
I tried looking it up and I found all sort of plane tessellations - but not $6^2*3^2$.

However, I did find information about [Trihexagonal tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihexagonal_tiling) which is a $(3.6)^2$ tessellation - are those the same?

I would appreciate any information (links are good too, a good picture would explain what tessellation this is) about this tessellation

Comment: I presume they have to be the same - certainly a quick construction shows that no regular $6^23^2$ vertex arrangement can be extended uniformly across the plane.  _Tilings And Patterns_ lists a couple of 2-uniform tilings that include a $6^23^2$, for instance $(6^23^2; 3^6)$ which you can get by replacing every third hexagon of the regular hexagonal tiling by an arrangement of six triangles.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - so if I understand right, this is the tessellation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trihexagonal_tiling_vertfig.png ?

Comment: well, the full tesselation is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tiling_Semiregular_3-6-3-6_Trihexagonal.svg - but yes, I suspect your article means $3 \cdot 6 \cdot 3 \cdot 6$.  Do you have a link (to the article) for reference?